# What is a "universal" cellular automaton exactly, what does it look like to compute "anything"?

Tags: computation-models, cellular-automata

About a [Universal Computer](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Universal_computer), this wiki says:

> A universal computer in a cellular automaton is a system that can compute anything that a Turing machine can compute (another term for this is Turing-complete). A cellular automaton in which such a system exists is called universal. A universal computer may be either infinite or finite, but when combined with a universal constructor, it is assumed to be finite.

A [Universal Constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universal_constructor) appears to be a self-replicating machine, so I won't focus on that just yet.

But what is a "universal computer" exactly? **What does it look like to be able to compute anything?**

I get that to compute anything means that it probably has all the necessary instructions (assuming instruction-set architecture) to run any theoretical program. But in terms of a cellular automaton, what does it mean to be a universal computer that can compute anything a Turing machine can? How does that generally look, or what are some specific examples of how it looks? Not necessarily the visible 2D cellular automaton graphics, but more how is the computation stored or implemented in the cellular automaton, basically?

I have been intrigued "cellular automata in hyperbolic spaces", but they too (like [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82481221.pdf) in *"A universal cellular automaton on the heptagrid of the hyperbolic plane with four states"*), they say it is a **universal cellular automaton**. What does it mean in that context? I get that it means it can compute anything, so I'm more wondering *what it looks like*, this being one example cellular automaton (in the hyperbolic space).

They describe a "locomotive" and describe the 4 states like this:

[image]

From that alone, I have no conception what they mean by "it can compute anything". Whereas with x86 or other instruction-set architectures, and with programming, you get a clear sense how the computer can compute things. I don't get a clear sense reading about universal cellular automata what "compute anything" looks like. What happens? What are some examples (such as using this hyperbolic one)? Basically I'm having trouble conceptualizing of what this looks like in specific examples.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis